# ping question (ubuntu vs windows)

Tags: ping

I have setup a ubuntu server on my home network. For the past 6 months I have been arguing with my ISP about packet loss. i would run pings from all my windows 10 boxes in my network and about every 15 or so packets it would timeout.
I now checked from my new ubuntu server and it drops exactly 0 packets to the same destination.
Does ubuntu do something different with ping than windows? Should I be looking at my windows boxes for NIC driver issues or something?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: While this is not a Windows forum I would recommend trying the following after such a thing occurs:  1) Click the start button 2) type "command" (if it doesn't show you a command terminal as an option enter "cmd" instead) 3) open terminal and enter "ipconfig /renew".  Renewing the settings of your Windows network connection may resolve some or all of these issues.  You could also choose to right click the terminal (CMD) in the search results and select "Open As Administrator " and then enter the ipconfig command, but not unless it doesn't work without the admin entry.  If this does not 1/2

Comment: resolve it then you need to change the settings in the device manager for the network device. 2/2

Answer (score 1):

The ping works the same on both.  Ping take parameters and the defaults for Windows and Linux are different.

Ping is a utility used for verifying the packets and being distributed to and from the source in a network and to check the errors.  If there are errors (packets lost) then, as you your legitimate concern, investigation is in order.

You have already verified by using two different computers, two different NIC's that the problem is unlikely your ISP.  Your message also suggests that you have isolated it to your Linux box, or cables between your Linux box and router if you are using cables.  If you check the cables and verify there isn't a problem with your cables, then you have most likely isolated it to your NIC or drivers for your NIC.  The next step in order may be to change NICs or check drivers for tne NIC you're using.

Some Network cards don't behave the best under Linux.  Some of the reason is that many hardware manufacturers provide closed-source proprietary drivers for Windows.  The Linux community is depended on volunteers to develop generic drivers using some industry standards that will work for many adapters.

If may be a case that it might take some work for you to get the best drivers for your card.

If you isolate the problem to your NIC.  Search for drivers and solutions for that particular hardware.  You might even post a new question that is specifically related to the hardware you're using and deal specifically with configuring the hardware.

Hope this clarifies your specific question concerning `ping`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think you misunderstood. The Ubuntu server is working 100% , its the windows machines that are dropping packets so I wanted to know if there was differences in the ping test they are running.

Comment: @Ciderza Only the default selected options when you provide no parameters to the ping commands.  If the issue is dropped packets on the Windows system then this question may need migrated to Super User as we do not support Windows here...

Comment: @ThomasWard Edit... you're right... typed before reading the user's comment.  There's a reason for your very high reputation.

Comment: @Ciderza No difference.  You appear to have isolated the problem to be related to your Windows computer or hardware drivers.  Take Thomas ward's suggestion.